# Pandas DateTime - System DownTime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

May I know any better way to get the system downtime period.

The system will detect a value and transmit its reading for every 20 minutes.

This code is used to identify the similar data of 0.00 that measured no data.
However, I would like to find out how long its had lost data in this consecutive timestamp.
Like an example, 2.20am, 2,40am, 3.00am having the same value, and thus the total lost time is 1hour.  Start time, end time in the dataframe. Please help.

```py
df_same_values = df.groupby((df['Water Quality Sensor'].shift() != df['Water Quality Sensor']).\
                  cumsum()).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3)
```

```
                  Water Quality Sensor
date                                     
2022-01-01 02:20:00              2.500000
2022-01-01 02:40:00              2.500000
2022-01-01 03:00:00              2.500000
2022-01-01 09:00:00              0.000000
2022-01-01 09:20:00              0.000000
2022-01-01 09:40:00              0.000000
2022-01-01 10:00:00              0.000000
2022-01-01 10:20:00              0.000000
2022-01-01 10:40:00              0.000000
2022-01-01 12:40:00              0.000000
2022-01-01 13:00:00              0.000000
2022-01-01 13:20:00              0.000000
2022-01-01 18:00:00              2.500000
2022-01-01 18:20:00              2.500000
2022-01-01 18:40:00              2.500000
2022-01-01 19:00:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 03:00:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 03:20:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 03:40:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 04:00:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 04:20:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 04:40:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 05:00:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 05:20:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 18:00:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 18:20:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 18:40:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 19:00:00              2.500000
2022-01-02 19:20:00              2.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data are truly this small, why not just iterate over the rows while recording appropriate values?

```
down_flag = False
down_start = None
down_stop = None

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Water Quality Sensor'] == 0 and down_flag == False:
        down_flag = True
        down_start = row['date']
    if row['Water Quality Sensor'] > 0 and down_flag == True:
        down_flag = False
        down_stop = df.loc[i-1, 'date']

down_time = down_stop - down_start

print(down_time)
```

gives

```
0 days 04:20:00
```

as expected.  Note this only records the last portion of downtime if there are multiple outages.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But, the downtime period is only concern when they are happening at the same time consecutively. Like an example, 9.00-10.00am each frequency is 20mins, therefore total downtime is 1hour. Apart from that another downtime occured at 10.40am, its defined as another downtime timestamp. T2 - T1, end time - start time

Comment: What value do you expect for the example data you gave?

Comment: The expected output are as below:
Water Quality Sensor = 2.5 
Start_Time             End_Time              Total_Down_Time
2022-01-01 02:20:00    2022-01-01 03:00:00      40 minutes    
2022-01-01 18:00:00    2022-01-01 19:00:00      60 minutes 
2022-01-02 03:00:00    2022-01-02 05:20:00     140 minutes 
2022-01-02 18:00:00    2022-01-02 19:20:00      80 minutes